# Base category and conditional logit coefficients in the multinomial logit model

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, multinomial-logit

Why do we need to use a base category (normalised to zero) when working with multinomial logit models?

Why do we need to report conditional logit coefficients?

Wouldn't marginal effects give us a better idea of the probability of belonging to a certain class?

Comment: One way to think about it: In a standard logit model, you don't have two equations, one for the "0" group and one for the "1" group; you just model the "1" group relative to the "0" group.

Answer (score 1):

You need a base category in order to interpret the log odds ratio. These are always in comparison with a reference category.

I am not sure about your other two questions: What do you mean by "reporting conditional log coefficient"?

You need the estimated coefficients of your output to calculate the probability of belonging to a certain class.

The marginal effects are not a probability of belonging to a class, but refer to  the marginal probability change if a variable is increased by one unit. These marginal probability effects can be discrete or based on derivatives, in which case they only hold for small changes in your independent variable.